# Not able to Read Xlsx file using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

The Scenario is: I am using .net mvc4 web application in which there is a form data that i have to first convert it into Excel format and download the file in format of .xlsx .for this i have used:

```
List<UploadDownload> listItems = new List<UploadDownload>();
listItems = uploadDownload.ConvertToList();
gridView.DataSource = listItems.ToList();
gridView.DataBind();
gridView.Dispose();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.xlsx");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-     officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gridView.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I successfully downloaded file (abc.xlsx) but when i want to read file using linq "Expected File Format" error show every time.

For Reading Downloaded(abc.xlsx) file i am using following code:

```
      var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();
        excel.FileName = filepath;
        var StepList = excel.Worksheet();
        var Steps = from s in excel.WorksheetNoHeader()

                    select (string)s[1];
```

please help me out.!

Comment: You need to use either office interop COM components, OLEDB data adapter, NPOI or similar third party libraries to create/read excel files. They have special binary structure; they are not simple strings attached end to end with an xlsx extension at the end. For the aforementioned libraries, there are plenty examples abound on the internet.

Comment: thanks mcy for sharing valuable knowledge with me ..!

Answer (score 1):

You can't just write the contents of a HTML grid into a file and then put a '.xlsx' extension on the file and give it the right content disposition and hope that Excel can read it.

Excel is expecting a Binary file (its actually a zip file) and it has a whole structure inside it that needs to be correct. If you copy a real excel file and change the extension to .zip then open it you'll see what I mean.

You need either to use a library to write the correct binary format that excel is expecting or write the grid in a CSV format and let excel open it and do the conversion

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply read an Excel `.XLSX` file without an appropriate library. Excel `.XLSX` file is a zipped XML based file format made by MS.

MS `Open XML SDK 2.5` is a good move I could suggest. Go through [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) .

An example code for reading `.XLSX` files : [READ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg575571.aspx)

Note : `Open XML SDK` is build targeting `.XLSX` file format (Which is an open xml file format). ANd it's kind of a successor to `Interop`

Comment: Hi ,thanks for quick response i have used Open XML SDK, here is the code for reading external file (.xlsx):                                                             string constr =string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", filepath);
            OleDbConnection Econ= new OleDbConnection(constr);
            string Query = string.Format("Select * FROM [{0}]", "Sheet1");
            OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(Query, Econ);
            Econ.Open(); giving me error " External table is not in the expected format."

Comment: I couldn't get you there. You create excel file using Open XML ? And now you want to download it and read the content ? AM I right :)

Comment: for downloading i have used the grid view binding approach with response output and for reading the file i have just created the constring using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and passed the filepath and then follow the above approach same as my previous comment

Comment: A good reference for OLEDB Excel reading : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB